# Set API URL based on Web.config appSettings

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, api

So I've an angular application that I've inherited that defines the API url as a constant variable and it works. However this has it's drawbacks as I have to change the variable value when I want to point at the deployment API, testing API and development API.

Is there a way to access my web.config file to read the appSettings and return the API URL? (I've applied different API URL'S using XML transformations).

I have implemented a solution that accesses an API controller from my web project and returns the value that way but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize values from web.config to JSON and add them to a `<script type="application/json">` element which your JavaScript can read and parse.

Here's the most pared-down example I can come up with. You'd probably want to better encapsulate both how you write this from your server code and how you read it from your JavaScript (and come up with better names.)

First, in your web.config, define the section which will contain the key/value pairs you want to pass to your JavaScript:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="jsConfigurationValues" 
          type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      </configSections>

      <jsConfigurationValues>
        <add key="someValue" value="a" />
        <add key="apiUrl" value="http://theurl" />
      </jsConfigurationValues>

      <!-- the rest of your web.config -->

    </configuration>
```

In the code-behind of a web form is this function.

```
protected string JavascriptConfigurationValues()
{
    var configurationValues =
        (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("jsConfigurationValues");
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach(var key in configurationValues.AllKeys) 
        dictionary.Add(key, configurationValues[key]);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
}
```

In the markup of the web form is this:

```
<script type="application/json" id="mySettings">
    <% =JavascriptConfigurationValues() %>
</script>
```

(You could put some or all of this in a UserControl or encapsulate it some other way.)

This script reads the JSON and assigns it to a variable:

```
var mySettings = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("mySettings").textContent);
```

Now it's accessible:

```
var apiUrl = mySettings.apiUrl;
```

Comment: There's a missing piece to this though, and that's the Angularish way to import this value into your Angular. Maybe you're better off calling one API from a relative URL to get the remaining set of environment-specific absolute URLs and letting the browser cache it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Scott I'll attempt to use this solution and hopefully I can resolve my problem.