# How can we access web.config value in java script file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to access this key 'urlReqCertiUploadIt' value inside js file when I click the button.

Comment: It might help if you explain why you need this. I don't think this is possible directly but we might be able to offer suggestions of alternative ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: This key doesn't exist in a button click event, can you explain what do you want to do ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Comment: I want to access this value because I need this into multiple js file. I am assigning this web.config value to a variable as per requirement.

Comment: javascript is client side (browser) code, but web.config is a server side file. With no additional coding it is not possible. You must do some coding to retrieve that info and send it to the browser. Edit your question and add the problematic code in it. Give us something to work with, atm it is too broad.

Comment: I would have a JS function named `function loadConfig(xxxx)` in the .js file and from the server side code register a javascript call to that function using the web.config value as a parameter.

Comment: Do note that client side validations should also be done server side to avoid malicious users bypassing them.

Comment: There are a number of answers for this question already. Try this one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181002/5101046

Answer (score 0):

In your view's javascript, add a var whose value will be set using razor syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someVariable = '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlReqCertiUploadIt"])';
</script>
```

Or you can add a property to your view's model that contains the value of that config setting, and set a JS variable in a similar way.

Then you can access this JS variable from other javascript referenced within/from that view.